# Overriding method with selector "tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

When I try to build in Xcode 6 GM, I get this error:

> overriding method with selector "tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? *** {
    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell

    var toDoItem:NSDictionary = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as NSDictionary
     cell.textLabel?.text = toDoItem.objectForKey("itemTitle") as? String


    return cell
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing part of the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature for that method changed in Xcode 6 GM.  It should be:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Which would make your function look like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var toDoItem:NSDictionary = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary
     cell.textLabel?.text = toDoItem.objectForKey("itemTitle") as? String


    return cell
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? The one you put in your question doesn't look complete.

Comment: sorry i think i've corrected functions parameters without changing inside the function thank you